# PGFplots problem : not the good graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I can't find what is going wrong in the following MWE, but the output is not at all the correct function, in this case `f(x) = \frac{4x^2}{(1+x)^2}`, which accepts a maximum for `x = 1`. Can anyone help me please ?

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\starttext
\starttikzpicture
  \startaxis[
    axis x line=bottom, xmin=0,xmax=5,     xlabel=$R/r$,
    axis y line=left,   ymin=0,ymax=1.5,     ylabel=$P/P_{\text{max}}$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},     anchor=north},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},     anchor=east, rotate=-90},
    samples=100, ticks=none, clip=false
  ]
    \addplot[mark=none,color=black, domain=0:5] {     4*x^2 / ((1+x)^2) };
    \draw [dashed] (0,1) node [left] {$1$} --     (1,1) -- (1,0) node[below] {$1$};
  \stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

[image]

## EDIT

Ok, the problem is just that I should stop working at 1 am... I made a mistake in the calculus, which leads to `\frac{4x}{(1+x)^2}` ; from the physical meaning, I knew it had to accept a maximum for x = 1, and I searched for a calculus error that I didn't find, and I finally lost faith in pgfplots. I will wait the following day to check my calculus next time.
Is there a way to tag this post as non-relevant ?

Comment: leading terms has 4/1 for the x^2 so I don't see the problem. Why do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Everything here seems fine, the `f(x)` you give will increase from `f(0)=0` and tending to a maximum of `4` as `x` goes to infinity

[image: Mathematica plot]

Maybe you are confusing the `x=1` and `x=-1` cases, `f(-1)` is indeed infinity

[image]

Playing around with ConTeXt I seem to get the same plot as I do with Mathematica above, with `f` tending to `4` for large `|x|` and diverging at `x=-1`.

[image]

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\starttext
\starttikzpicture
  \startaxis[
    axis x line=bottom, xmin=-20,xmax=20,     xlabel=$R/r$,
    axis y line=middle,   ymin=0,ymax=40,     ylabel=$P/P_{\text{max}}$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},     anchor=north},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},     anchor=east, rotate=-90},
    samples=100, ticks=none, clip=false
  ]
    \addplot[mark=none,color=black, domain=-0.75:20] {     4*x^2 / ((1+x)^2) };
    \addplot[mark=none,color=black, domain=-20:-1.5] {     4*x^2 / ((1+x)^2) };
    \draw [dashed] (-1,50) -- (-1,0) node[below] {$-1$};
    \draw [dashed] (-20,4) -- (20,4) node[midway, above left] {$4$};
  \stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```